# unable to find valid certification path to requested target android studio

Tags: android-studio

I see this error: Can not find the valid certification path to the requested target

I try to solve it by following the proposed answers, but it does not work. Can you help me please.

Comment: would you provide further details of the case and the error?

Comment: 12:12 Gradle sync failed: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2m 2s 97ms)

Comment: A problem occurred configuring root project 'AndroidEc2lt'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
     Required by:

Comment: project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom'.